# iOS / iPhone- Hiding one button when another is clicked

Tags: iphone, hide, uiswitch

I have a settings view in my app which has a couple of buttons (actually UISwitches). If the "off" setting on one of the switches is selected, I'd like to hide the second switch immediately. Can this be done?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
```

write the above 2 lines in your .h file and set the outlets with XIB.

Now create a method called `hideButton`

```
-(IBAction)hideButton
{
       btn1.hidden = YES;
}
```

in XIB attach this method with `btn2`.
So now when you click on `btn2` it will hide `btn1`.

Comment: how about if button is set to an Action?

Answer (score 4):

Connect the two switches as outlets. lets say switch1 & switch2.

Connect this function to the valueChanged action.

```
- (IBAction)mySwitch1:(id)sender { 
    [switch2 setHidden:!(switch1.isOn)];
}
```

Now when switch1 is not on then switch2 will be hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Add a target to the first switch which on value change calls the instance of the second switch and hides it.

Add the target:

```
    [switch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Calls this method:

```
- (void) switchToggled:(UISwitch*)switch {
 if ([switch isOn]) switch2.hidden = YES;
 else switch2.hidden = NO;
}
```

NJones if statement is more effective though.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4

---

Within your function do the following:

```
btn1.isHidden = true
```